# Max date won't work, alternative?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, max, temp

I read through some of the answers but couldn't find the right answer for the following question. I have the below query that runs:

```
SELECT 
    mbr_src_code as 'C',
    cst_recno as 'ID',
    ind_first_name as 'FN',
    ind_last_name as 'LN',
    cst_org_name_dn as 'Company',
    cst_ixo_title_dn as 'Title',
    MAX(inv_trx_date) as 'Latest Transaction',
    inv_add_user as 'User',
    pyd_type as 'Type',
    bat_code as 'Code',
    mbr_add_user 'Add User',
    mbr_rejoin_date as 'rejoin',
    mbt_code,
    adr_state as 'state',
    adr_country as 'country',
    ivd_amount_cp
FROM 
    mb_membership  
JOIN 
    co_customer ON cst_key = mbr_cst_key AND mbr_delete_flag = 0  
LEFT JOIN 
    mb_member_type ON mbr_mbt_key = mbt_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    co_customer_x_address ON cxa_key = cst_cxa_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    co_address ON cxa_adr_key = adr_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    co_individual ON ind_cst_key = cst_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    mb_membership_x_ac_invoice ON mxi_mbr_key = mbr_key 
LEFT JOIN  
    ac_invoice ON mxi_inv_key = inv_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    ac_invoice_detail ON ivd_inv_key = inv_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    ac_payment_detail ON pyd_ivd_key = ivd_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    ac_payment ON pyd_pay_key = pay_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    ac_batch ON pay_bat_key = bat_key 
LEFT JOIN 
    ac_payment_info ON pay_pin_key = pin_key
LEFT JOIN 
    co_customer_x_customer ON cxc_cst_key_1 = co_customer.cst_key 
                           AND (cxc_end_date IS NULL OR DATEDIFF(dd, GETDATE(), cxc_end_date) >= 0) 
                           AND cxc_rlt_code = 'Chapter Member' 
LEFT JOIN 
    co_chapter ON cxc_cst_key_2 = chp_cst_key  
WHERE 
    (mbr_src_code LIKE N'%1DMFY18%' OR mbr_src_code LIKE N'%2DMFY18%' 
     OR mbr_src_code LIKE N'%INPhoneFY18%' OR mbr_src_code LIKE N'%OBTMFY18%' 
     OR mbr_src_code LIKE N'%3DMFY18%') 
    AND cst_recno = '20239'
GROUP BY  
    mbr_key, mbr_src_code, cst_recno, 
    ind_first_name, ind_last_name, cst_org_name_dn, cst_ixo_title_dn,
    inv_add_user, pyd_type, bat_code, mbr_add_user, mbr_rejoin_date,
    mbt_code, adr_state, adr_country, pin_cc_number_display, pin_cc_cardholder_name,
    ivd_amount_cp, chp_name
ORDER BY
    ind_last_name
```

and I get the following result(sample):

```
      C       ID    FN    LN       Company          Title       Latest transaction     User              Type          Code                    Add User    rejoin   mbt_code           state  country    ivd_amount_cp     
    2DMFY18 20239   Gus Bauman  Beveridge & Diamond Attorney    2013-09-23 00:00:00 Membership Renewal  Payment 2013-09-23-ULI-USD-C-SP-01  ULI_Conversion  NULL    Associate Member    DC  UNITED STATES   430.00  
    2DMFY18 20239   Gus Bauman  Beveridge & Diamond Attorney    2014-08-04 00:00:00 Membership Renewal  Payment 2014-08-04-ULI-USD-C-SP-01  ULI_Conversion  NULL    Associate Member    DC  UNITED STATES   430.00  
    2DMFY18 20239   Gus Bauman  Beveridge & Diamond Attorney    2015-09-02 00:00:00 Membership Renewal  Payment 2015-09-02-ULI-USD-C-SP-02  ULI_Conversion  NULL    Associate Member    DC  UNITED STATES   440.00  
    2DMFY18 20239   Gus Bauman  Beveridge & Diamond Attorney    2016-09-12 00:00:00 Membership Renewal  Payment 2016-09-12-ULI-USD-C-SP-01  ULI_Conversion  NULL    Associate Member    DC  UNITED STATES   440.00  
    2DMFY18 20239   Gus Bauman  Beveridge & Diamond Attorney    2017-09-22 00:00:00 Membership Renewal  Payment 2017-09-22-ULI-USD-C-SP-01  ULI_Conversion  NULL    Associate Member    DC  UNITED STATES   440.00
```

So my MAX function doesn't work(probably because there are other columns with different value,just like in inv_trx_date) , what would be the best alternative to use? I would like to basically take the whole query and select MAX(inv_trx_date) as 'Latest Transaction' per each unique cst_recno as 'ID'.

Comment: Please edit the code in your question to be the absolute minimum that shows the problem (hint: you don't need any joins and only a couple of columns to achieve that).

Answer (score 1):

I think the canonical answer to this question is as follows

```
with AllData as
(
select ... from ...
where ...
)
select * from allData ad1
inner join 
(
    select pk1, pk2, pk<n>, max(MaxThing) MaxVal 
    from AllData
    group by pk1, pk2, pk<n>
) as ad2 
on (ad1.pk1=ad2.pk1 and ad1.pk2=ad2.pk2 and ad1.pk<n>=ad2.pk<n> 
and  ad1.MaxThing=ad2.MaxVal)
```

In your case `cst_recno` is the PK and `inv_trx_date` is the MaxThing

Answer (score 0):

MAX works over the entire group you have specified. If you want the MAX aggregation to work for each unique `cst_recno` then you need to group by only each unique `cst_recno`.

Comment: It doesn't work, if I group by cst_recno only. It needs to be grouped by all columns in the select statement but the one with an aggregate function(MAX(inv_trx_date) as 'Latest Transaction',)

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'mb_membership.mbr_src_code' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You cannot select `mbr_src_code` because it is not unique to the group, you either need to add that column to the group by clause, remove it from the select clause, or do an agrigate over it in the select clause.

Comment: I need to include all those columns(query above) in the result though.

Comment: How would I do a temp table from the result I have above and THEN select MAX(inv_trx_date) as 'Latest Transaction'? Is that feasible?

Comment: You would need to do a join on either the temp table that you selected results you wanted into, or you could just join on a a nested query

Comment: Thanks Burnham. Would you be kind and give me an example with the query above?

Comment: Add `INSERT INTO #myTempTable (col1, col2, col3, ....)` to the top of the above query, and then `Select ID, MAX([Latest Transaction]) FROM #myTempTable GROUP BY ID` what you want from that table in a query right below it.

Comment: I can't figure it out. This is how my query starts:                               
WITH CTE as(
SELECT distinct
mbr_src_code as 'C',
cst_recno as 'ID',

Comment: and then I am trying to add a condition on my CTE at the end, something like select MAX(inv_trx_date) as 'Latest Transaction',cst_recno as 'ID' from CTE group by cst_recno

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking anymore, but I think it is outside the scope of your original question. I don't see any CTE in the original query you posted.

Comment: None of your suggestions worked(not able to implement them) and so I asked for an example with the above query since I think I am not implementing your advice correctly. I tried to use a temp table but didn't work.                                                                                                
Would you take the above query and add a code so I get MAX(inv_trx_date) as 'Latest Transaction' per cst_recno as 'ID' ? @MBurnham

Answer (score 0):

The issue of duplicate rows is because your `CODE` and `ivd_amount_cp` columns contain non-unique values in the recordset. Had they all contained the exact same information, your `MAX` function would have worked without any problems.

You will have to use a Common Table Expression, as others have suggested. Let's assume you have a table that contains a specific CustomerID, and order dates, as well as a lot of other information. A customer can place multiple orders on the same date, and for whatever reason, we're only interested in the latest order of that customer. However, we do want to see all information related to that order.

The first thing we do is build a CTE to identify which order is the latest:

```
/* Example table */
CREATE TABLE myOrders
(
    OrderID int IDENTITY(1,1)
    , CustomerID int 
    , OrderDate datetime
    , ImportantInfo nvarchar(255)
)
;

/* Some test data to work with */
INSERT INTO myOrders 
VALUES (
    1, '01-01-2017', 'We do not want this row'
), (
    1, '01-02-2017', 'We do not want this row either'
),  (
    1, '01-10-2017', 'Getting closer, but not this one either'
),  (
    1, '01-10-2017', 'This is the one we want!'
)
;

WITH myMaxOrder AS 
(
    SELECT CustomerID, MAX(OrderID) AS MaxOrderID
    FROM myORders
    GROUP BY CustomerID
)
```

Once you identified the `MAX` of whatever you need, you then simply use that to identify all the other data you want to retrieve, by using the CTE to join back to the original table using the values you just obtained in the CTE:

```
SELECT 
    o.* 
FROM 
    MyOrders o
    JOIN myMaxOrder o1 ON o.CustomerID = o1.CustomerID 
    AND o1.MaxOrderID = o.OrderID
```