# SQL query to retrieve single row of multiple duplicate id's

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to retrieve single latest record based on time for each id.
For example, if i pass id's as **1 & 2**, the result should be 2 rows as mentioned below.

For example:

**Employee Table**

```
##############################################
id                      time
##############################################
1           04-04-18 06:46:55.191000000 PM
1           04-04-18 06:43:30.846000000 PM
1           04-04-18 06:38:30.968000000 PM
2           04-04-18 06:33:32.811000000 PM
2           04-04-18 06:28:32.337000000 PM
2           04-04-18 06:23:31.256000000 PM
3           04-04-18 06:16:53.395000000 PM
3           04-04-18 06:13:30.292000000 PM
3           04-04-18 06:08:30.652000000 PM
```

**Expected Result**

```
##############################################
id                      time
##############################################
1           04-04-18 06:46:55.191000000 PM
2           04-04-18 06:33:32.811000000 PM
```

I tried query mentioned below, but this gives single result. 
Tried other options, could not help. Any suggestions please?

```
SELECT * FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.id IN ('1','2') 
ORDER BY CREATED DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I select only the first distinct match from a field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15010763/how-can-i-select-only-the-first-distinct-match-from-a-field-in-mysql)

Comment: What is your primary key field called?

Comment: No primary key, entries available with duplicate id key.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
emp.id, MAX(emp.time) as EmpTime
FROM Employee emp 
WHERE emp.id in (1,2)
GROUP BY emp.id 
ORDER BY emp.id
```

Comment: I have other columns as well in table, and i need to fetch all the columns. I need with select *.

Comment: see my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671164/max-date-wont-work-alternative/46681270#46681270

Comment: Did not help, looks like issue with syntax, i am trying with oracle.    ORA-00905: missing keyword error.                                                          select * from Employee ad1
inner join 
(
    select MAX(time) 
    from Employee
    group by id
) as ad2 
on (ad1.id=ad2.id and ad1.time=ad2.time)

Comment: Not sure.  You do need to select `ID` from your sub select and maybe also you need an alias for the `MAX(time)` column

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use a `Group By` operator:

```
SELECT emp.id, emp.time FROM Employee emp WHERE emp.id in (1,2) GROUP BY emp.id ORDER BY ....
```

Comment: This did not work, It gives error related group by expression. I need query to fetch all columns, i have other columns in table which i have not mentioned. May be select * would be helpful.